# Unable to save keras model in databricks

Tags: keras, databricks, azure-databricks

I am saving keras model

```
model.save('model.h5')
```

in databricks, but model is not saving,

I have also tried saving in `/tmp/model.h5` as mentioned [here](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/32260/can-a-tensorflow-model-be-savedloaded-directly-to.html)

but model is not saving.

The saving cell executes but when I load model it shows no `model.h5` file is available.

when I do this `dbfs_model_path = 'dbfs:/FileStore/models/model.h5' dbutils.fs.cp('file:/tmp/model.h5', dbfs_model_path)`

OR try loading model

`tf.keras.models.load_model("file:/tmp/model.h5")`

I get error message `java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/model.h5 does not exist`

Comment: provide information on error message (if exists), and also information about your setup - Databricks Runtime version, etc.

Comment: when I do this 
`dbfs_model_path = 'dbfs:/FileStore/models/model.h5'
dbutils.fs.cp('file:/tmp/model.h5', dbfs_model_path)  `


OR try loading model


`tf.keras.models.load_model("file:/tmp/model.h5")`

I get error message


`java.io.FileNotFoundException: File file:/tmp/model.h5 does not exist`

Comment: Databricks runtime version is 7.5 ML (includes Apache Spark 3.0.1, GPU, Scala 2.12)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that Keras is designed to work only with local files, so it doesn't understand URIs, such as `dbfs:/`, or `file:/`.  So you need to use local paths for saving & loading operations, and then copy files to/from DBFS (unfortunately `/dbfs` doesn't play well with Keras because of the way it works).

The following code works just fine.  Note that `dbfs:/` or `file:/` are used only in the calls to the `dbutils.fs` commands - Keras stuff uses the names of local files.

- create model & save locally as `/tmp/model-full.h5`:

```py
from tensorflow.keras.applications import InceptionV3
model = InceptionV3(weights="imagenet")
model.save('/tmp/model-full.h5')
```

- copy data to DBFS as `dbfs:/tmp/model-full.h5` and check it:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("file:/tmp/model-full.h5", "dbfs:/tmp/model-full.h5")
display(dbutils.fs.ls("/tmp/model-full.h5"))
```

- copy file from DBFS as `/tmp/model-full2.h5` & load it:

```py
dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/tmp/model-full.h5", "file:/tmp/model-full2.h5")
from tensorflow import keras
model2 = keras.models.load_model("/tmp/model-full2.h5")
```

Comment: when I try to load the model I get the following error: ```ValueError: Unknown layer: table_mask. Please ensure this object is passed to the `custom_objects` argument. See https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/save_and_serialize#registering_the_custom_object for details.```